# this is how to calculate dates in excel using functions

Tags: excel, math

In `2017` the Islamic month of fasting, Ramadan, began on Friday, 26 May. What fraction of the year was this? I calculated it manually as `146/365`, but I am looking for an excel formula to calculate it.

Comment: Did you check how many days are in the Islamic or Hijri calendar?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the date when Ramadan began on Cell `A1`, then:

```
=A1 - DATE(YEAR(A1),1,0)
```

or

```
=A1 - DATE(YEAR(A1),1,1)+1
```

will give you the Ramadan day of the year, to get the fraction:

```
=(A1 - DATE(YEAR(A1),1,0))/(DATE(YEAR(A1),12,31) - DATE(YEAR(A1),1,1)+1)
```

or using `LET` to avoid repetition:

```
=LET(r, A1, y, YEAR(r), (r-DATE(y,1,0))/(DATE(y,12,31) - DATE(y,1,1)+1))
```

You can replace the denominator using a leap year condition as follows:

```
=LET(r, A1, y, YEAR(A1), (r-DATE(y,1,0))/(365+IF(MONTH(DATE(y,2,29))=2,1,0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
=YEARFRAC(start_date,end_date)
```

whereby, your start_date: `1/1/2017`, and your end_date: `5/26/2017`